# Can it be used with 'to staff' or 'staff' in the sentence

Tags: grammar

I saw a news on CNN US.

**"NASA requires staff to telecommute at Alabama center after employee tests positive for coronavirus".**

So, my question is that the sentence should be "NASA requires ***to*** staff~". however, it doesn't contain the 'to'.
Is it because NASA requires that staff to telecommute at ~?

Comment: Why do you think there should be "to staff"?  Is it because you think "staff" is an infinitive verb, or is staff a noun and "to" a preposition?  Please explain what rule of grammar you are using.

Comment: @JamesK thought, the 'staff' using as Object. but im not familiar with grammar much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is correct as it is, and it does contain a 'to' - it's right before "telecommute", the verb which is being required.  The *to* in "*required to X*" constructions (such as *I was required to run*) is part of the infinitive form of the verb X - *to run*, *to talk* - so it stays 'glued' to the X, rather than the 'requires', when an object is added (*I require you to run*, *Nasa required staff to telecommute*).

Comment: got it. it's similar something like "I want you to be there"